# A value without a type name was found and no expected type is available

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I want to update my fields:

```
    {
      "Activitiy": [
        {
            "LookupId": 110,
            "LookupValue": "110"
        }
      ] 
    }
```

But I got an incorrect response. How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Your question is not clear... Could you please elaborate and be more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the Code below to update the lookup field value of a list item.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#UpdateListItem").click(function(){
        var listName="TestLookupREST";
        var listItemId=1;
        var itemType = GetItemTypeForListName(listName);
        var itemData={
            "__metadata": { "type": itemType },
            "ActivitiyId": 110
        };
        UpdateListItem(listName,itemData,listItemId);
    });
});
function UpdateListItem(listName,itemData,listItemId){     
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items("+listItemId+")",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(itemData),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
            "If-Match": "*"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Success');
            window.location.href=window.location.href;
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
}

// Get List Item Type metadata
function GetItemTypeForListName(name) {
    return "SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.split(" ").join("").slice(1) + "ListItem";
}    
</script>
<input id="UpdateListItem" type="button" value="UpdateListItem"/>
```

If the lookup field allow multiple values, we can use this.

```
var itemData={
    "__metadata": { "type": itemType },
    "ActivitiyId": { "results": [110, 111] }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! But I have a question - what is mean itemType?

Comment: itemType is ListItemEntityTypeFullName of a list, example, custom list name is "Test", the itemType is "SP.Data.TestListItem". Document library name is "DL", the itemType is "SP.Data.DLItem". https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest#working-with-list-items-by-using-rest